# How can I make a table_query.sql?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sql, postgresql

https://github.com/blobmon/simplechan
I am going to the street on the above site. Now I am making databases and users.
Come out of psql by pressing ctrl + D and also come out of postgres user by pressing ctrl + D again. From there,

```
$ psql - d simplech_db - U simplech_role
```

After entering, I tried to make tables and functions.

```
\ i create_table_query.sql

\ i functions.sql

\ i functions_moderator.sql
```

Even if you enter, nothing will react. There is no error.
I am doing it on Linux, but where was the problem? please explain. Also, I am going on Linux (ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

The file doesn't exist and the readme you are using is outdated. I would suggest contacting the owner of that repository.